# Php Replace Seem Not To Work

Tags: php, html, replace, symbols

I am trying for an hour to make the replace working. There is really no reason why it shouldn't work, but it is just not working.

```
echo $title22;
$title22 = str_replace('–','dsdas',$title22);
echo $title22;
```

output:

```
Something – something else
Something – something else
```

I guess that i use wrong kind of this symbol: –, but i have tried the both option on my tastature and none of them work. Does replace works with the symbol or not?

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the character? Are you sure it isn't encoded in some way? Have you checked the source?

Comment: this is the first thing I did. This is the title of a Wordpress post and i copied the symbol from the editor as well as on the output page. No luck.

Comment: I do not know about encoding.

Comment: How? I just see charset=UTF-8 on the header, but I do not know anything else about encoding.

Comment: Why negative votes. This just doesn't work and if you know the reason let me know. This is a wordpress post title and when i copy the symbol from the title and try to replace it is doesn't work at all.

Comment: As said check the source of the page whether the characters are really like you think they are.

Comment: This is what i have done in the first place. I did urlencode and got :%26%238211%3B for the  - .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works:

```
$title22 = urlencode($title22);
$title22 = str_replace("%26%238211%3B", "thisqqqqqsymbol", $title22);
$title22 = urldecode($title22);         
$title22 = str_replace("thisqqqqqsymbol", $color."-", $title22);
```

I am not sure what %26%238211%3B is. I guess something broken.

Also this is an universal solution for problems with strange characters like this.

Answer (score 0):

The - is not equal to the – character:
Try this:

```
$title22='Something – something else';
echo $title22;
$title22 = str_replace('–','dsdas',$title22);
echo $title22;
```

Output:

```
Something – something else
Something dsdas something else
```

Comment: I already tried - and –. And it doesn't get replaced in both cases.

Comment: Run my sample please, that works (I tested it on my system before posting)

Comment: The sample works, but on my site it doesn't work. I think that php is sometimes really really bad  and doesn't work properly.

Comment: Strange. Maybe add this info to your question and add php info to see what might cause that. Also update your sample code above since that will never work due to the different dashes.

Comment: @Brana I can assure you PHP does work properly. Your code is wrong.

Comment: I solved it using urlencode. Now it works. This is problem with wordpress and php mot with my coding. There is no reason to code - as this strange char.

Comment: Ok. All the millions of people successfully replacing characters in PHP are just being lucky that by some sick twist of the universe for all of them it works.

Comment: They are not lucky, I am unlucky.